# How to install KMDF Filter Driver from WDK 8.1 Toaster Sample Driver?

Tags: windows, installation, kmdf, filter-driver

I'm learning Windows driver development by examining the WDK 8.1 [Toaster Sample Driver](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Toaster-7d256224). I can build, install, debug, and communicate with the KMDF Bus, and KMDF Function Driver. The problem I have is installing the KMDF Filter Driver. I tried using devcon to install the filter driver, but it always fail. Any help would be appreciated.

**Host system**:

- Windows 8.1 Pro x64
- Build: Visual Studio 2013 Pro and WDK 8.1
- Debug: WinDbg (named pipe)

**Target system (virtual machine)**:

- Windows 8.1 Enterprise Evaluation
- Kernel debugging, and test signing, enabled
- Install: devcon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on OSR website:

- http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=446
- http://osronline.com/showThread.CFM?link=238603

Apparently, the installation procedure for a KMDF Filter driver is different than other KMDF drivers. See installation procedure below:

1. Move the "filter.sys" file to Windows drivers directory (C:\Windows\System32\drivers).
2. Create a service for the driver using the path above as your **binpath**. I used **demand** as my start type.
3. Add an UpperFilter multi-string value to the TOASTER class registry, and add the service created in step 2 to the UpperFilter.
4. Restart the TOASTER device.